# Finding the graph of a function based on its properties

Tags: calculus

I know the following things about my function: $f(–4) = f(2) = 0;  f '(-1) = 0,  f '(x) < 0 \text{ for }x < -1;  f '(x) > 0 \text{ for }x > -1$

That is, it appears to be a quadratic function with intercepts at 2 and -4.

How can I determine its equation?

Comment: Is it given in the question that the function is quadratic?

Comment: No, that was an assumption on my part. Probably not a valid one.

Comment: You can't determine the equation. But you can easily graph this funcion. You know the x-intercepts and you know that the function is decreasing for x less than -1 and increasing for x greater than -1 and at x =-1 you have a critical point.

Answer (score 1):

Consider any function of the form $f_n(x) = (x + 1)^{2n} - 3^{2n}$.

If we substitute any natural number for $n$ in the above equation, the resulting equation will fulfill all of the descriptions you gave. So, your description describes a set of functions, not a single one.

$n = 1$ would yield the quadratic you're looking for: $f_1(x) = (x + 1)^2 - 9 = (x + 4)(x - 2)$. The derivative of this is $f'_1(x) = 2(x + 1)$, which will be 0 at $x = -1$, negative whenever $x < -1$ and positive when $x > -1$.